# Объясните код. И что запрашивает ContentResolver query?

Tags: java, android-sdk, activity

[image]

Объясните (и поправьте) что происходит в этом коде:

Код:

Родительская Activity.

```
public class ContactPickerTester extends Activity {
    public static int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contentpickertester);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_contact_button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View _view) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Uri.parse("content://contacts/"));
               startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
            }
        });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resCode, Intent data) {
        switch (reqCode) {
            case (PICK_CONTACT): {
                if (resCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Uri contactData = data.getData();
                    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
                    c.moveToFirst();
                    String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY));
                    c.close();
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selected_contact_textview);
                    tv.setText(name);
                }
                break;
            }
            default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

Дочерняя Activity.

```
public class ContactPicker extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_picker);

        final Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        String[] from = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.itemTextView};
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitemlayout, c, from, to, 0);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contactListView);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                c.moveToPosition(pos);
                int rowId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
                Uri outUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, rowId);
                Intent outData = new Intent();
                outData.setData(outUri);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, outData);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

(3) получаем объект Cursor в котором содержится таблица из контент провайдера содержащего контакты, а ContactsContact.Contacts.CONTENT_URI - это ссылка на таблицу в ContentProvider.

(4) Получаем значение столбца "_id" по его индексу. Так?

(5) Это что и зачем? Как я понял, берем путь к таблице в ContentProvider и добавляем дальнейший путь к столбцу "_id". Так?
Далее пакуем в Intent и отправляем родительской Activity.

(1) После получения data из пришедшего Intent с помощью метода query запрашивает уже непосредственно Cursor, который будет содержать столбец "_id".

(2) И вот тут я запутался.
Зачем метод getString? Как я понял для получения какого-то значения у столбца.
Но внутри запрашивается у Cursor индекс столбца DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY. Но как? Если в курсоре только строки из столбца "_id".

Пожалуйста поправьте меня там где я неправ.

Comment: Добавьте код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: "Дочерняя активность" - больно смотреть на такие названия.

Comment: Ну а как ее обозвать?

Comment: Хотя бы не активность а активити, так вас с больше вероятностью поймут. Я надеюсь вы интент не называете "намерение"?

Comment: Нет, не называю. Ну так кто-нибудь мне ответит по существу?

Answer (score 1):

> (1) После получения data из пришедшего Intent с помощью метода query
>   запрашивает уже непосредственно Cursor, который будет содержать
>   столбец "_id".

Нет, он будет содержать полные данные, по тому id который мы запросили, все остальное понято верно.

Comment: То есть с помощью c.moveToPosition(pos); переходим на указанную строку и в дальнейшем работаем с ее столбцами?

Comment: Да, и там же формируем outUri в котором будет id нужной нас строки. Потом мы его скормим `ContentResolver`-у он выдаст нам `Cursor`  с единственной строкой, на которую мы и становимся методом `c.moveToFirst()`, и вытаскиваем из нее нужные данные методом `c.getString()`

Comment: @KnightsForce на startandroid гляньте 101 урок он практически аналогичный